# 2-level nested object JSON built with Express NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to build a JSON from three SQL related tables: A, B and C. I'm unable to do it correctly by using JavaScript on Express and Node. The following represents desired JSON to be built:

```
[
    "A": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Aname",
        "B": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Bname",
                "C": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Cname",
                        ...
                    }
                ],
                ...
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    },
  ]
]
```

The current JavaScript code I wrote is the following:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM A WHERE active = 1", (err, a_rows, results) => {
  json_result = [];
  if(!err) {
    a_rows.forEach(function(a_row, index) {
      json_result.push(a_row);
      db.query("SELECT * FROM B WHERE a_id = ? AND active = 1", [a_row.id], (err, b_rows, results) => {
        if(!err) {
          b_json_result = [];
          b_rows.forEach(function(b_row, index) {
            b_json_result.push(b_rows);
            db.query("SELECT * FROM C WHERE b_id = ? AND active = 1", [b_row.id], (err, c_rows, results) => {
              if(!err) {
                b_json_result.slice(-1)[0].C = c_rows;
              }
            });
            json_result.slice(-1)[0].B = b_json_result;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
  if(json_result.length > 0) {
    res.status(200).jsonp(json_result);
  } else {
    res.status(404).jsonp(json_result);
  }
}
```

I'm sorry but what am I doing wrong about building this JSON?

Comment: One big issue is db.query is asynchronous so you can't `send()` until all the queries complete (and add to the object tree). Suggest you use a promise based query package. Some allow use of promise OR callback so check docs of the one you are already using

Comment: Also not common these days to use `jsonp`. Is that an intentional implementation as opposed to json? The client side requests are quite different for the two

Comment: I notice the async side effect by having empty array in b_json_result variable. How should I overcome this? @charlietfl

Comment: Again using promise chain would be easiest

Comment: You should just combine all 3 queries with `JOIN`.